# how to add dynamic input field in a dynamic form react js

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react js, I have implement dynamic input fields in a dynamic form. Basically The dynamic form is for stroing the questions of MCQ test, and the dynamic input field is required for storing options for the MCQ test.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this if you want to add both questions and responses dynamically

```
const [form, setForm] = useState([
  { label: "", responses:  [{ value: "", isRightResponse: false }]}
]);
      
return(
...   
<button
  onClick={() => {
    const formCopy = [...form];
    formCopy.push({ label: "", responses: [{ value: "", isRightResponse: false }] });   // Here you add 2 input fields (1 question and 1 response)
    setForm(formCopy);
  }}
>
Add Question
</button>
{form.map((question, key) => (
  <div className="..." key={key}>
    <label>Question {key + 1}</label>
    <button
      onClick={() => {
        const formCopy = [...form];
        formCopy[key].responses.push({value: "", isRightResponse: false});  // Here you add one input field as a response for the selected question
        setForm(formCopy);
      }}
    >
    Add response
    </button>
    <input
      type="text"
      value={question.label}
      onChange={(e) => {
        const formCopy = [...form];
        formCopy[key].label = e.target.value;
        setForm(formCopy);
      }}
    />
    {question.responses.map((response, index) => (
      <div key={index}>
        <label>Response {index + 1}</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={response.value}
          onChange={(e) => {
            const formCopy = [...form];
            formCopy[key].responses[index].value = e.target.value;
            setForm(formCopy);
          }}
        />
        <label>Right response ?</label>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          defaultChecked={response.isRightResponse}
          onChange={(e) => {
            const formCopy = [...form];
            formCopy[key].responses[index].isRightResponse =
              e.target.checked;
            setForm(formCopy);
              }}
            />
      </div>
    ))}
  </div>
))}
...
)
```

Same logic if you want to remove responses or questions